# How to remove duplicate items during training CNN?

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm working on image classification problem by using CNN. I have an image data set which contains duplicated images. when I train the CNN with this data, it has over fitting. Therefore, I need to remove those duplicates.

Comment: if this is a small data set you can just remove with hand duplicated image. If there is just few duplicated and lot of image it'll not really impact you'r learning algorithm. Remove duplicated image has to be done before training you'r conv net. If there is thousand of image, and you can't find duplicated image with their ID or name, you can use euclidian distance to compare  a  given target image to all other image and remove image where euclidian distance = 0. This si probably requiring a lot of computing ressources and may be you can find more efficient way to do this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What we loosely refer to as duplicates can be difficult for algorithms to discern.
Your duplicates can be either:

1. Exact Duplicates
2. Near-exact Duplicates. (minor edits of image etc)
3. perceptual Duplicates (same content, but different view, camera etc)

No1 & 2 are easier to solve. No 3. is very subjective and still a research topic.
I can offer a solution for No1 & 2.
Both solutions use the excellent image hash- hashing library: https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash

1. Exact duplicates
   Exact duplicates can be found using a perceptual hashing measure.
   The phash library is quite good at this. I routinely use it to clean
   training data.
   Usage (from github site) is as simple as:

```
from PIL import Image
import imagehash

# image_fns : List of training image files
img_hashes = {}

for img_fn in sorted(image_fns):
    hash = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open(image_fn))
    if hash in img_hashes:
        print( '{} duplicate of {}'.format(image_fn, img_hashes[hash]) )
    else:
        img_hashes[hash] = image_fn
```

2. Near-Exact Duplicates
   In this case you will have to set a threshold and compare the hash values for their distance from each
   other. This has to be done by trial-and-error for your image content.

```
from PIL import Image
import imagehash

# image_fns : List of training image files
img_hashes = {}
epsilon = 50

for img_fn1, img_fn2 in zip(image_fns, image_fns[::-1]):
    if image_fn1 == image_fn2:
        continue

    hash1 = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open(image_fn1))
    hash2 = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open(image_fn2))
    if hash1 - hash2 < epsilon:
        print( '{} is near duplicate of {}'.format(image_fn1, image_fn2) )
```

Answer (score 1):

the solution from @nav is quite good for finding Near-exact Duplicates and Exact Duplicates.
Since your use case is to train a neural network and similar images cause your evaluation to overfitting, then it might be wiser to remove any kind of similarity.

I find this project to do image deduplication https://github.com/idealo/imagededup

and with CNN algorithm in the project, you can remove cases of perceptual Duplicates (which also remove near-exact and exact duplicates)