# Removing duplicate images while scraping images from google

Tags: opencv, python-imaging-library

I took code from here: [How to remove duplicate items during training CNN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56564128/how-to-remove-duplicate-items-during-training-cnn/66686208#66686208)

```
from PIL import Image
import imagehash

# image_fns : List of training image files
img_hashes = {}

for img_fn in sorted(image_fns):
    hash = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open(image_fn))
    if hash in img_hashes:
        print( '{} duplicate of {}'.format(image_fn, img_hashes[hash]) )
    else:
        img_hashes[hash] = image_fn
```

How can we append images in img_hashes,which is an empty dict?
when executing if statement how program checks if hash is in img_hashes?

Anyone has any idea?

Thank you

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ not scrapping. Scrapping means throwing things away like rubbish

Comment: Ok. Thanks @banny